# A problem with indices in tensor

Tags: tensors, index

I want to create a tensor similar to the one shown in the first picture, but I'm encountering some issues with indices. Could anybody assist me?
Here's my code:

```
(HoldForm[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*
SubscriptBox[
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["R", "TI"], "~"], 
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"j", "k"}], "TI"]] \*
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"\[PartialD]", 
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["u", "TI"], "_"], 
StyleBox["i", "TI"]]}], 
RowBox[{"\[PartialD]", 
SubscriptBox[
StyleBox["x", "TI"], 
StyleBox["k", "TI"]]}]]\)]) == (Plus @@@ 
Table[Subscript [HoldForm[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["R", "TI"], "~"] \*
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"\[PartialD]", 
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["u", "TI"], "_"]}], 
RowBox[{"\[PartialD]", 
StyleBox["x", "TI"]}]]\)], i, j , k], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 
  3}] // MatrixForm)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might start by defining a function to display the individual "atomic" bits:

```
IndexedExpression[i_, j_, k_] := 
  HoldForm[
    Subscript[OverTilde["R"], i, k]  TraditionalForm[D[Subscript[OverBar[u], j], Subscript[x, k]]]]

IndexedExpression[j, i, k]
```

[image]

Then we can make a table:

```
Table[IndexedExpression[a, b, c], {b, 1, 3}, {a, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

A couple more steps to get to the final form:

```
IndexedExpression[j, i, k] == 
  MatrixForm[
    Apply[
      Plus, 
      Table[IndexedExpression[a, b, c], {b, 1, 3}, {a, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}], 
      {2}]]
```

[image]

I'm not sure if you just want a pretty picture or if you're going to need to assign values or do computations, but hopefully this gets you started.